# How to create a jar using SBT in Scala?

Tags: scala, sbt, package, config

My project directory is as follows:

```
src/main/resources/ 
src/main/scala/
```

I want to package a jar so when I unzip it will look like this:

```
project.jar  ->   com.project   <class file>
             ->   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  -> Class-Path: ./lib/dependence1.jar ./lib/dependence2.jar
```

So it need some way to copy the dependences jars to the lib directory.

How to config the build.sbt file?

Comment: Do you really need your dependencies to be under "lib"? JAR files have a particular structure better left alone. This is how Java knows where to find stuff. Let `sbt-assemply` figure out how to build the jar, it should work for all use case.

Answer (score 3):

Using the native SBT `package` command will only include your code without the dependencies.

If you want to include all the dependencies in an `uber-jar` then I suggest you take look at [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin.

Here is an example project (`build.sbt` file):

```
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._
import AssemblyKeys._

name := "ToyProject"


lazy val coreLibrary = Project("ProjectName", file(".")).settings(customAssemblyOptions: _*).settings(
  version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
)


lazy val customAssemblyOptions = sbtassembly.Plugin.assemblySettings ++ Seq(
    test in assembly := {},
    assemblyOption in assembly ~= { _.copy(includeScala = false) }, // Do not package Scala (suggested)
    assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := { // to Exclude spesific files (not entire Jars)
        case PathList("lib", "static", "Windows", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
        case _ => MergeStrategy.first
    },
    excludedJars in assembly <<= (fullClasspath in assembly) map {
      cp =>
        cp filter {
          c => List(
            "example-2.1.jar", // Remove these jars in case you want to keep all jars from being added to the uber jar. 
            "example-3.3.jar"
          ) exists {
            c.data.getName contains _
          }
        }
    }
  )
```